# How to make a list of variables in Magma (computer algebra system)?

Tags: math-software, sagemath, magma-cas

In **sagemath**, for making a list of variables like $ Z=[z00,z01,z02, ... ,z97,z98,z99] $ we can use this code: 
`sage: Z = list(var('z%i%i' % (i,j)) for i in range(10) for j in range(10))`

In **Magma**, it is easy to make a list like $Z=[[0,0],[0,1],[0,2],...,[9,7],[9,8],[9,9]] $ with this code: 
`> Z := [[i,j]: j in [0..9], i in [0..9]];`
, but now I try to make a list in Magma that its elemnts are variables such as $z00$ ,not lists like $[0,0]$. How can I make a list of variables in Magma?

In this regard, I found this useful appendix [The Magma Language](https://ecc2017.cs.ru.nl/slides/magma.pdf).
It introduced this code:
`> printf"z%o%o" , 0, 0;` for printing $z00$
, but `"z%o%o" , 0, 0;` is not work in a list or in a loop such as `for`.

(`'z%i%i' % (i,j)` is a code that used in each part of sagemath such as a list, but in Magma `“z%o%o ”, 0, 0;` works only with `printf` and we cannot use it for making a list in Magma )

Comment: What do you want to do with the generated variables?

Comment: `l := [ ]; for i in [1..10] do   l[i] := i; end for; l;`

Comment: Thank you so much @Somos, your previous answer was correct. But now I want to make PolynomialRing with this list. For example in  **sagemath**  we can use this code: `P = PolynomialRing(GF(2), [str(i) for i in Z], order='lex')` for making this PolynomialRing with a list like Z. In **Magma**, how can I make this PolynomialRing with this list?

Comment: .... `R := PolynomialRing(Integers(), #l);` then the variables are `R.i`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this as an example of what can be done.

```
v := ["z" * IntegerToString(i) : i in [0..3] ];
Z := IntegerRing();
S := PolynomialRing(Z, 4);
AssignNames(~S, v);
p := S.1 + 2*S.2^2 + 3*S.3^3 + 4*S.4^4;
p;
```